# AdMob: is it allowed to setVisibility(GONE) to banners for specific views?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, admob, adbannerview

I have a fragment with a `ViewPager`. I am showing an **AdMob** banner of the bottom of the fragment.

For a specific page I would like not to show the banner, as I want to use the whole screen space to display the information.

Is it allowed to `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the banner for a specific page, then back to `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` for the other pages. Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: In case the banner revenue is also based on the impression time, I am wondering if AdMob my think hiding the banner is a non-fair behaviour

Answer (score 1):

It's allowed.

What isn't allowed are 2 banners in one activity !

Answer (score 1):

Be careful though, you should call adView.pause(), when not showing the banner and adView.resume() when showing it again. This way your app will not mess with your and Google's statistics